# Bind to custom input properties in C# Precompiled Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, precompiled

I am attempting to use Custom Bindings and Patterns to Create an HTTP Triggered Azure Function that gets a file from Blob Storage. In my case the POST HTTP Request would know the attachment name.
In [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions-and-patterns) the documents discuss the pattern using csx scripting, I am using the Precomipled C# Azure Functions in Visual Studio. I tried to translate it to the following but it throws a run-time exception:

> The following 1 functions are in error:
>   Run: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'HttpTriggerGetAttachmentBlob.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No binding parameter exists for 'Attachment'.

Here is the Code:

```
    public class BlobInfo
    {
        public string Attachment { get; set; }
    }
    public static class HttpTriggerGetAttachmentBlob
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTriggerGetAttachmentBlob")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function,
            "post")]
            HttpRequestMessage req, 
            TraceWriter log,
            [Blob("strings/{Attachment}")] string blobContents,
            BlobInfo blobInfo)
        {
            if(blobContents == null) {
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                data = $"{blobContents}"
            });
        }
    }
```

How does one retrieve a Blob Storage file knowing the filename coming in from a Triggered event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is actually to put `HttpTrigger` attribute on `blobInfo` parameter, not `req`:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req,
  TraceWriter log,
  [Blob("strings/{Attachment}")] string blobContents,
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] BlobInfo blobInfo)
```

That will tell runtime that you are binding to `BlobInfo` class, and it will be able to derive `{Attachment}` template binding.

Note: be sure to delete `bin` folder before you recompile, the tooling doesn't always update the existing `function.json` file properly.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `BlobTrigger` request another `Blob`? My understanding is the two options are `String` or `Stream`.

Comment: Based on [trigger usage docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger---usage), you can't